# Specifying value attribute in @PropertySource in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

**SETUP**

I have one jar (say its A) which adds another jar (say its B) as its dependency through `Maven`. Jar A is from Spring Boot Application.

**ISSUE**

> I have properties file in jar B under its path src/conf/. Am trying to set the path value in the value attribute  of @PropertySource in one of java file in jar B. When trying to do it, it refers the src/conf of jar A. How can i achieve this.

`@PropertySource(
     value = {
     "file:${spring.profiles.path}other-services-dev.properties" })`

Here `spring.profiles.path` gets its value from the deployment script of jar A

Answer (score 1):

Use "classpath:" instead of `file:`.

Make the property file a resource of jar B by moving it to `src/main/resources`. Then you can reference the file like this: `@PropertySource("classpath:/other-services-dev.properties")`.

The better approach, which has better encapsulation, would be to define a class in jar B, which is annotated `@PropertySource("classpath:/other-services-dev.properties")`, and exposes the properties through getters. Then jar A can simply let this class be injected.

In jar B:

```
 @PropertySource("classpath:/other-services-dev.properties")
 @Service
 class BProperties
   @Value("${setting1}")
   private String setting1;

   public String getSetting1() {
     return setting1;
   }
 }
```

In jar A

```
@Service
class SomeService {
  @Autowired
  private BProperties properties;
}
```